# $f$ have finitely many critical points in $\Omega$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, stationary-point

Assume that $\Omega$ is an bounded open set in $R^m, f\in C^2(\overline{\Omega},R^m)$. If $f$ does not have any critical point in $\partial \Omega$, and all the critical points of $f$ in $\Omega$ are non-degenerate, prove that $f$ has finitely many critical points in $\Omega$.

Note that $a$ is a critical point of $f$ if $\nabla f(a)=0$, and a critical point $a$ is said to be non-degenerate if $\det H_f(a) \neq0$. Here $H_f$ denotes the Hessian matrix of $f$.

A few observations: $\overline{\Omega}$ and $\partial \Omega$ are both compact. Hence $f$ obtains its extreme value in $\overline{\Omega}$, and the restriction of $f$ i.e. $f|_{\partial\Omega}$ also obtains its extreme value. And, take maximum value for example, $\max_{x\in \partial\Omega} f(x) \leq \max_{x\in \overline{\Omega}} f(x)$. Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a cover of your set $\bar \Omega$: The set $R=\{x\in \bar \Omega : \nabla f(x)\neq 0\}$ is open (because the function is $C^1$), then the function $\det H_f(x)$ has a sign (because $f\in C^2(\Omega) )$ in some small ball $B_{\epsilon_i}(x_i)$ centred in the nondegenerate critical point $x_i$. The family $R,\cup_i B_{\epsilon_i}(x_i)$ covers $\bar \Omega$. Now use the compactness to conclude.

Comment: Hi Jonas. I can follow most of your answer, but the last "use the compactness" part is a bit beyond me. I know that there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\overline{\Omega} \subset ((\cup_{1\leq j \leq N} B_{\epsilon_{n_{j}}}(x_{n_j})) \cup R).$ If $x \in \Omega$ is a critical point, then $x \in (\cup_{1\leq j \leq N} B_{\epsilon_{n_{j}}}(x_{n_j}))$. But what should I do next?

Comment: Choose $\epsilon_i$ so small such that each ball contains only one critical nondegenerate point.

Comment: But what permits us to make such a choice? Is there anything to do with "then the function $\det H_f(x)$ has a sign?" And I'm afraid that I am not sure what does "$\det H_f (x)$ has a sign" imply. Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: The fact that $\det H_f(x)$ has a sign in a small ball implies that in $B_{\epsilon_i}(x_i)\setminus \{x_i\}$ we have $\nabla f(x) \neq 0$, hence we have only one critical nondgenerate point for for each ball. By compactness you prove that we have only a finite number of such balls.